# Creating vector layer (Shapefile) with QgsNewVectorLayerDialog

Tags: qgis, shapefile, pyqgis, vector

I'm using the following code that displays a window to create a new Shapefile:

```
from qgis.gui import QgsNewVectorLayerDialog

new_vector_layer_dialog = QgsNewVectorLayerDialog()
new_vector_layer_dialog.show()
```

How can I put a flag on the Polygon by code, and not the line or the point?

Also when you press the `OK` button, how to get the dialog to select where to save the Shapefile?

When you click `OK`, it does not create a Shapefile, but just closes the dialog box. Additionally, it does not create a vector layer in the `Layers Panel`.

What do I need to do to create the layer and load it into the `Layers Panel`?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @vazagena! Are you wanting to do this from a plugin or from the python console?

Comment: It is desirable and there and there, since in the beginning the task is to get acquainted, and then make a button in the module

Comment: If you can tell via the console python please in qgis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the static method `runAndCreateLayer` instead of `show`:

```
from qgis.gui import QgsNewVectorLayerDialog

layerPath = QgsNewVectorLayerDialog().runAndCreateLayer()
if layerPath:
    layer = QgsVectorLayer(layerPath, 'new layer', 'ogr')
    QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
```

---

Concerning the Polygon radio button, the dialog doesn't seem to let you do that. You could do something like this:

```
myDialog.findChild( QRadioButton, 'mPolygonRadioButton').setChecked(True)
```

Which will be nonetheless overwritten when calling `runAndCreateLayer`.

*Note: The [`QgsNewVectorLayerDialog` class](http://qgis.org/api/classQgsNewVectorLayerDialog.html) for QGIS 3 lets you set a CRS. Setting geometry type could be a feature request for QGIS.*